# Excel VBA copy values that meet criteria to specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to build a To Do list in excel. I decided to write a macro that checks for specific conditions and if met copies the to do item.

I'm a VBA beginner so spent time hunting around and learning and put together the code below. Please could you look at it and offer some help on these points?

- It copies correctly, but I'm not sure how to change the line with `.End(xlUp)` to paste to specific cell I20, and fill downwards with each item.
- when pasting, overwrite existing content in cells (so each day I click the update button, it 
  overwrites the previous days)

Thanks for the help,

```
Sub today()
Dim StartDate As Long
Dim EndDate As Long

StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) + 6)

For Row = 1 To 100

    If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 6).Value >= StartDate And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 6).Value <= EndDate And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 4).Value <> "Complete" Then

        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 2).Copy

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    Next Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
   Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Row, 2).Copy

   Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

You could try

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count,"I").End(xlup).offset(1,0).value = worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row,2).Value
```

I think you are referencing the right cell (last cell + 1 row), but that the `ActiveSheet.Paste` is messing it up. Next to that copy/pasting is  slower than just getting the value.

EDIT: If you want to start at I20, but I19 is not filled, you can first determine the row before setting the value:

```
Dim rowNum as Long
rowNum = application.worksheetfunction.max(20,Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count,"I").End(xlup).offset(1,0).Row)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNum,"I").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row,2).Value
```

Comment: That change makes it run a lot smoother, but still doesn't display in I20. My understanding is that offset is what makes it display each item in a new row, so the change would be making the offset start from I20 instead of the top of the column.

Comment: The cell you are referencing points to the last filled cell in Column I + 1 row. Is I19 filled?

Comment: Oh, no it isn't! I didn't realise it looked at the last filled cell. That part works well now. Is it possible (without changing the code completely) to overwrite the rows each time the macro is run instead of it filling the next empty row?

Comment: You will need to clear column I at the start of the macro then with something like this: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I20:I" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count,"I").end(xlup).Row).ClearContents`

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you for the help. Is it normal on Stackoverflow to edit the original question and add another code section for the updated code answer?

Comment: You mean that you add my answer to your question? I guess you can do that, but if you check my answer as the one you used, than it's also clear.